# No Visual Robot Model with URDF

Tags: ros, simulation, urdf, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i write in terminal

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/02-multipleshapes.urdf
```

result

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'urdf/02-multipleshapes.urdf'
```

And no RViz display ,so and no robot
i use groovy please i need help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127356/no-visual-robot-model-with-urdf/) by [M Samir](https://answers.ros.org/users/9326/m-samir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `model` parameter takes either an absolute or relative path. For a relative path, you have to make sure that it is reachable from the current working directory. So before you run the above command, you have to be in the `urdf_tutorial` directory already, as the `urdf` directory is a subdirectory of `urdf_tutorial`.

To use a relative path:

```
roscd urdf_tutorial
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/02-multipleshapes.urdf
```

Or, you could do this, which works from any directory:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=`rospack find urdf_tutorial`/urdf/02-multipleshapes.urdf
```

`rospack find PKG_NAME` will first try to find the package you gave it, and then returns the absolute path to that package. As you now have an absolute path to the urdf, this works regardless of what is your current working directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0